# Remove comma only from number separators (regular expression grouping)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a column of alpha-numeric string in pandas dataframe.
The goal is to only remove comma from number separators. For example:

```
Hello, world! -> Hello, world!
```

but

```
Warhammer 40,000 -> Warhammer 40000
Codename 1,337 -> Codename 1337
```

I can deduce that only when both sides are numerics '[0-9]+,[0-9]+' do I want to remove the comma. However, I can't seem to figure out a way to keep the same digits. Could someone help? If related, the size of the dataframe is a few hundred thousand rows and an average string is about 100 words.

p.s. this is my first post. I tried searching for related issue but found none. English is not my mother-tougue, chances are, I might have missed the keyword for this issue. Please do link me to the right place should this happens. Many thanks and much appreciated :)

Update: added the keyword 'grouping' as reminder for myself.

Comment: Does pandas replace help? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: What I missed is the grouping in regular expression: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @uingtea regex, but for `pandas dataframe`, you can do in this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['Hello, world!', 'Warhammer 40,000', 'Codename 1,337']})
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'(\d+),(\d+)', r'\1\2', x))
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to capture the digits into group `(\d+),(\d+)`

```
import re

items = ['Hello, world!', 'Warhammer 40,000', 'Codename 1,337']

for item in items:
  item = re.sub(r'(\d+),(\d+)', r'\1\2', item)
  print(item)
```

Results:

```
Hello, world!
Warhammer 40000
Codename 1337
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pandas' `str.replace()` with a regular expression:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    "Hello, world!",
    "Warhammer 40,000",
    "Codename 1,337",
    "Total USD 1,27",
    "1,080,000,000 kilometers per hour"
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["title"])
df["title"] = df["title"].str.replace(",(\d{3})", "\\1")
df
```

which yields

```
    title
0   Hello, world!
1   Warhammer 40000
2   Codename 1337
3   Total USD 1,27
4   1080000000 kilometers per hour
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex and vanilla python this might help:

```
import re

def convert_commas(old):

    new = []
    pattern = re.compile(r"\d+,\d+")
    for word in old.split():
        if re.findall(pattern, word):
            word = word.replace(',','')
        new.append(word)

    new = (" ").join(new)
    return new

print(convert_commas(old))
```

Can then use this function as a callback with map on the column to convert the commas for example

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need. please refer below screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
str = 'hello, world! 40,000 and 50,000!'
str = re.sub(r'(\d+),(\d+)', r'\1\2', str)
```

Comment: Please consider some explanatory text.